# Get the full range which the cell is part of

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a full range - `A1:D12`

In my script I want to have this range in a variable so I could add a new line to it.

The idea is that this range is dynamic so it will change every time I add a new line.

This script takes the first cell of the range (it is basically A1 cell):

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startrow = 1;
  //the starting cell of the range
  var startingCell = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
```

But now I want to get the full range which A1 is part of.

How do I do it ?

Comment: I see, this is an Excel VBA function `range("A1").CurrentRegion`. You may find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187688/select-contiguous-range-in-app-script-for-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

If you are only adding new rows, and each row has something in the A column, you can do this:

```
function getNextEmptyRow() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET ID").getSheetByName("SHEET NAME");
    var column = sheet.getRange('A:A');
    var values = column.getValues();
    var ct = 0;
    while (values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "") {
        ct++;
    }
    //return (ct + 1); // Next row.
    return ct; // Last row with something in it.
}
```

to do something like this:

```
var range = 'A1:D' + getNextEmptyRow();
```