# Google sheet: How to match a null value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a sheet I have rows with unknown number of values, because these values come from user input.
For example, in Row 2 there are values in B2, C2, D2; in Row 3 there are values in B3 only; and in Row 4 there are values in B4, C4, D4, E4, F4. Column A is ID so it's irrelevant for this question. I want to get these values in a function like

```
function getRowValues(row){
 ....
}
```

1. In my actual case, there won't be blank cells in between valued cells, so I think I only need to find the first null cell in a row, and then use `getRange` accordingly. I've tried `match("",B2:2)` and `match(null,B2:2)` they all return errors. So match can't be used to match NULL values? I can think of other ways to do this like doing a `isblank` loop through the range, also I can do `hlookup` or `filter`, but since I have to run this functions against the whole row, I am afraid they will be quite resource consuming, hence are not very good practices. Is this concern well-founded?
2. Just for learning purpose, if I do have blank cells in between valued cells, what is the best way to get only non-blank values in a row?

Comment: The `getContiguousRange()` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187688/select-contiguous-range-in-app-script-for-spreadsheet) may be of interest. This will pull in any data in column A - and it assumes there is a completely blank row immediately following the last row of data you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

As for the second question I think this is a quite convenient way:

```js
var arr1 = ["a", 1, "", , "b", 3];

var arr2 = arr1.filter(String);

console.log(arr2); // output: [ 'a', 1, 'b', 3 ]
```

In case you don't need to remember which element to which column belongs.

Probably this trick is an answer for your first question as well. Something like this:

```
function getRowValues(row) {
    return row.getValues().flat().filter(String);
}
```

But the best practice is to get all rows via `range.getValues()` as a 2D-array and process the array rather than getting values from every row:

```
function main() {
  var sheet    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range    = "B1:Z5";
  var data_raw = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();
  var data     = data_raw.map(row => row.filter(String));
  Logger.log(data)
}
```